# Computing the curvature of $\mathcal{O}(-1)$ from its pull back to $\mathbb{C}^{n+1}\setminus \{0\}$

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry, vector-bundles, kahler-manifolds

I saw in different places a way to compute the curvature of $\mathcal{O}(-1)\to \mathbb{P}^n$ by pulling it back by the projection $\pi:\mathbb{C}^{n+1}\setminus \{0\}\to \mathbb{P}^n$.

As a matter of fact, the line bundle $L:=\pi^*\mathcal{O}(-1)\to\mathbb{C}^{n+1}\setminus \{0\}$ is trivial, with a trivializing section $\sigma:z\mapsto z$. We can compute easily its curvature
$$\Theta_L(z)=\bar{\partial}\partial\log||z||^2=\bar{\partial}\partial\log \sum_{i=0}^n|z|^2.$$

I do not understand now how to relate that (despite its obvious resemblance) to the curvature of $\mathcal{O}(-1)\to \mathbb{P}^n$ which is given for example in the chart $U_0=\{[z_0:...:z_n]|z_0\neq 0\}$ by
$$\Theta_{\mathcal{O}(-1)}(z)=\bar{\partial}\partial\log (1+\sum_{i=1}^n|z|^2).$$
There are formulae for pull back curvatures but not for "pushforward" curvatures. I feel that this is quite simple but do not get how exactly.

Comment: The local coordinates $z^i$ on projective space are _ratios_ of Cartesian coordinates on the affine space. Specifically, if $(Z^0, \dots, Z^n)$ are Cartesian coordinates on $\mathbf{C}^n$, then for each $j$ we get coordinates $z_j^i = Z^i/Z^j$, $i \neq j$, on the set $Z^j \neq 0$.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang I did get that, but how does it help to obtain $\Theta_{\mathcal{O}(-1)}$ from $\Theta_L$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\dd}{\partial}\newcommand{\ddbar}{\bar{\dd}}$Let $(Z^{0}, Z^{1}, \dots, Z^{n})$ denote Cartesian coordinates. For each $j$, if we write $z_{j}^{i} = Z^{i}/Z^{j}$ on the open set where $Z^{j} \neq 0$, we have
$$
\log \sum_{i=0}^{n} |Z^{i}|^{2}
= \log \biggl[|Z^{j}|^{2} \sum_{i=0}^{n} |z_{j}^{i}|^{2}\biggr]
= \log|Z^{j}|^{2} + \log \biggl[1 + \sum_{i\neq j} |z_{j}^{i}|^{2}\biggr].
$$
The function $\log|Z^{j}|^{2} = \log Z^{j} + \log \bar{Z}^{j}$ is annihilated by $\dd\ddbar$; taking $j = 0$ and writing $z^{i} = z_{0}^{i}$ we have
$$
\ddbar\dd\log \sum_{i=0}^{n} |Z^{i}|^{2}
= \ddbar\dd\log \biggl[1 + \sum_{i=1}^{n} |z^{i}|^{2}\biggr].
$$

Comment: I still have two problems: 1- why can we compute the curvature of a line bundle using its pullback, is it specific to here, to any submersion? Are there specific conditions to make that possible? 2- more specifically in your computation the operators $\partial,\bar{\partial}$ on the left hand side are taken with respect to the coordinates $Z^i$. On the r.h.s it should be taken w.r.t the local coordinates $z_j$

Comment: To address 2 first, we can view $1 + \sum_i|z^i|^2$ as defined on $\mathbf{C}^{n+1}$. Alternatively, this sum is defined on the affine hyperplane $Z^0=1$, a holomorphic coordinate chart for projective space on which $Z^j = z^j$. For 1, the Chern _class_ of a holomorphic line bundle (the $(1,1)$-class represented by $-i/2\pi$ times the curvature of the Chern connection) is natural with respect to pullback by smooth maps; and the _form_ is natural with respect to holomorphic maps.